# forming new small lists from a combination set of two lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two patterns of lists inside a big list.

```
[[5.35, 5.09, 4.95, 4.81, 4.75, 5.19], [3601.0, 3602.0, 3603.0, 3600.0, 3610.0, 3600.0],[..,..,..,],[..,..,..],...]
```

To put in simple words, it is a combination of

> [ [pricesList1], [DurationList1], [PricesList2], [DurationList2],... ]

I now want to create a new list with the price and corresponding duration from both lists as a pair from each set. For Example :

```
[[[5.35,3601.0],[5.09,3602.0],[4.95,3603],[4.81,3600],[4.75,3610],....],[[p1,d1],[p2,d2],[p3,d3],..],[[],[],[],..],....]
```

I have tried using `List<List<Object>>` and `List<List<String>>`. But no use. How can I do this?

I programed as following, which is wrong :

```
List<List<Object>> DurationList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<List<Object>> FinalList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<List<String>> SlotList = null;
for(int pair=0; pair<(FinalList.size()-1) ; pair=pair+2)
                {
                    for(int innerloop=0; innerloop<(FinalList.get(pair).size());innerloop++)
                            {
                            SlotList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                            SlotList.addAll((Collection<? extends List<String>>) (FinalList.get(pair).get(innerloop)));
                            }
                }
for(int pair=1; pair<(FinalList.size()) ; pair=pair+2)
                {
                    for(int innerloop=0; innerloop<(FinalList.get(pair).size());innerloop++)
                            {
                            SlotList.addAll((Collection<? extends List<Object>>) FinalList.get(pair).get(innerloop));
                            }
                }
```

Comment: `List<Map<String, String>>`?

Comment: How is the first list declared (exact data types)?

Comment: if you know that the number of elements in the price and durationlists always have the same length you can loop the pricelist and pick the data from both lists by index and store them in a new list.. or map

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `List` to represent those pairs ? It looks like using your own class definition would be more helpful (could use .getPrice() / .getDuration() instead of .get(0) / .get(1), no risk of incorrectly inserting more than 2 values, etc.)

Comment: @AlexShesterov would the List be of any use here, instead of just a map?

Comment: Aaron is right, might be better with an object to keep the pairs and keep the objects in a single list or set (to avoid dupes)

Comment: Yes. I know the size and they are exactly same. It is like [[priceList1 with 24 elements], [duration list1 with 24 elements], ...]. Such 7 combination lists exists . i.e, 7 price lists and 7 duration lists. Every price list is followed by its own duration list in sequence.

Comment: No.. I haven't tried Maps as I am a very basic programmer in java and I am unaware of usage of Maps. Hence I used list

Comment: Price list and double lists are of list<string> datatype. but the big list i.e, combination of both is of List<List<Object>> datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input list always has an even number of sublists and pairs of sublists have the same size, you can use a `for` loop iterating over the outer lists's element two by two :

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<outerList.size(); i+=2) {
    List<String> priceList = outerList.get(i);
    List<String> durationsList = outerList.get(i+1);
    for (int j=0; j<priceList.size(); j++) {
        List<String> newEntry = new ArrayList<>();
        newEntry.add(priceList.get(j));
        newEntry.add(durationsList.get(j));
        result.add(newEntry);
    }
}
```

As commented I suggest defining your own class to store the price and duration rather than using that `List<String> newEntry`.